# What is this sensor/device located near the master bath tub?

Tags: electrical, bathroom, usa

This thing was in my old house and the new owner is asking me what it is. I never knew, and asked a few people. It is the size of a standard electrical outlet socket, and it is located near the master bath tub.

Another detail of note is that the master closet is behind it, and it contains the alarm and ethernet/coaxial wiring boxes.

[image: Odd sensor near master bath tub]

Comment: Removing face-plate (two screws) should tell.  Could it be intercom from front door? Vent to exhaust moist air?

Comment: My guess would be humidity sensor to activate the bath fan.

Comment: I should have asked when I lived there, but the ventilation fan never turned on by itself, there was a switch. I think I took it out once and there were no markings of significance on it...I can't now though. Thought someone might just know.

Comment: Could it be a chime connected to the doorbell?

Comment: -1 for not posting a picture without the cover

Comment: When the alarm goes off - is there a speaker in this box ? Near the Master Bath tub - How near ? Service Access for CB - jacuzzi tub ?? 
Does this thing chime when a window or door is open .. take the cover off and look inside.

Comment: @jsotola Read the post , the "new owner" is asking what it is . That means the OP is the old owner and probably does not live there anymore just a guess on my part though - he probably asked the new owner for the picture of it. Then again maybe he has an old key and can simply waltz in and get us a picture of the guts.. :-)   Perhaps a little leniency is in order at least he has a picture of the thing. Cheers.

Comment: @Ken your guess was correct. New home owner actually got back to me. It is a siren for the alarm system. I'd give you the answer if it was an answer...

Comment: @JustinP8 - I posted it as the answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posting per the ops response to my comments:

When the alarm goes off - is there a speaker in this box ?

The unit is an Alarm Buzzer - removing the cover will reveal a speaker .